# MongoDB assertion error "ECONNREFUSED"

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
AssertionError: null == {"name":"MongoError","message":"connect ECONNREFUSED"}
```

I got an AssertionError.

I try to use NodeJS AND MongoDB and I'm following tutorial from Github.

I got that error from this code below :

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
, assert = require('assert');
console.log(1);
// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';
// Use connect method to connect to the Server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
console.log(2);
assert.equal(null, err);
console.log(3);
console.log("Connected correctly to server");

db.close();
console.log(4);

});
console.log(5);
```

At console, 1,5,2 is marked.

I installed assertion module. What is the problem?

I executed 'mongod' (actually I don't know if I did it correctly). After executing, 1,5,2 is marked, before that, 1,5,2 is not marked and got an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the ECONNREFUSED, I would say your server is not running.  If you are running it from console, try re-starting it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to run the server `mkdir -p /data/db` then `sudo mongod` and it should all be working well.